# Inserir uma valor na tabela SQL para cada checkbox selecionado

Tags: php, html, mysql, formulário, checkbox

Tenho um formulário com um grupo de checkbox (igual abaixo) e gostaria que ao selecionar os valores, inserisse uma linha na tabela do SQL para cada checkbox selecionado:

```
<form>
   <input type="hidden" id="id_pedido" value="123">
   <div>
     <input class="uk-checkbox" type="checkbox" value="16.15"> Adicional 1
   </div>
   <div>
     <input class="uk-checkbox" type="checkbox" value="23.75"> Adicional 2
   </div>
   <button id="concluir" name="concluir" class="uk-button uk-button-primary" type="submit">Concluir</button>
</form>
```

Aí ao selecionar os 2 valores, a tabela MYSQL (cv_contratos_adicionais) deveria ficar assim assim:

```
id  |  id_pedido  |  valor   |  servico
1   |     123     |   16.15  |  Adicional 1
2   |     123     |   23.75  |  Adicional 2
```

Isso é o que tenho até o momento, a parte dos checkbox e que preciso saber como "quebrar" o valor e nome do serviço:

```
<body>
     <?php
    if(isset($_POST['concluir'])){
        $sql = "INSERT INTO cv_contratos_adicinoais (id_pedido, valor, servico)
        VALUES ('".$_POST["id_pedido"]."','".$_POST["valor"]."','".$_POST["servico"]."')";
    }

    ?>

    <form method="post"> 
       <input type="hidden" name="id_pedido" id="id_pedido" value="123">
       <div>
         <input class="uk-checkbox" type="checkbox" value="16.15"> Adicional 1
       </div>
       <div>
         <input class="uk-checkbox" type="checkbox" value="23.75"> Adicional 2
       </div>
       <button id="concluir" name="concluir" class="uk-button uk-button-primary" type="submit">Concluir</button>
    </form>

</body>
```

Comment: e o que vc já tentou fazer? aliás, qual linguagem server está usando?

Comment: to usando php, eu tentei usar o INSERT INTO cv_contratos_adicionais, aí ele insere, o problema é que daí vem todos os checkbox como um unico valor e não em linhas separadas

Comment: você precisa colocar seu código completo, o php que está usando para inserir e para montar a página senão vai ser difícil ajudarmos

Comment: editei, e coloquei la o que tenho até o momento

Comment: coloque name nos checkbox e recupere com post, e alias onde está o mysqli_query($sql) no seu código?

Answer (score -2):

Você está fazendo certo agora adicione o atributo nome como um array nas checkbox:

```
<input name="adicional[]" class="uk-checkbox" type="checkbox" value="16.15"> Adicional 1
<input name="adicional[]" class="uk-checkbox" type="checkbox" value="23.75"> Adicional 2
```

E no back-end faça um loop no array que vai retornar para inserir as checkboxs que foram selecionadas:

```
if(isset($_POST['concluir'])) {
    $sql = "";

    for($i = 0; $i < count($_POST["adicional"]); $i++) {
        $sql .= "INSERT INTO cv_contratos_adicinoais (id_pedido, valor, servico)
            VALUES ('".$_POST["id_pedido"]."','".$_POST["adicional"][$i]."','".$_POST["servico"]."');";
    }

    echo $sql;
}
```

Essa é a sintaxe básica para trabalhar com múltiplas checkboxs, para passar os adicionais você tem algumas opções...

- Adicionar mais um checkbox invisível para cada adicional e, por JavaScript, habilitar e desabilitar quando o checkbox visível for clicado
- No PHP, verificar o valor do checkbox e atribuir o valor do adicional
- Se usado AJAX, pode adicionar um outro atributo aos checkbox que vai ser lido e passado para o PHP

Problemas: na 1ª e na 2ª situação você terá uma boa quantidade de código extra (10 `input`s ou `if else`/`switch case` a mais), na 1ª e na 3ª os valor podem ser facilmente mudados no front-end, além dos valores, o nome deve-se validar no back-end.

A primeira acho um pouco gambiarra desnecessária. Se seu código tiver apenas duas checkbox e não vai ser adicionado mais nenhuma, aconselho a segunda opção. Se seu código pode vir a ter algumas checkbox recomendo o uso do AJAX.